# Can I do a Joined report on Lookup(User) and Date Fields

Tags: reporting

I have 2 objects that I would like to do a join report on. The standard Activity Object and a custom object. They both have lookup fields to the User object and a date field. Is it possible to do a joined report in Salesforce on these 2 fields for these 2 objects?

Answer (score 1):

**Create a Custom Report Type (Setup -> Report Types)**

- Select "Users" as primary Object (A)
- Select your "Custom Object" as the secondary object (B)

**Create another Report Type for:**

- Primary: "Users"
- Secondary: "Activities (Assigned To)"

**Create a report and select "Joined Report"**

- Select the above new report types as your Block 1 and Block 2
- Select "Full Name" as the Group Across Blocks
- Make sure that the filters are correct

Comment: Thanks man; it never occurred to me that the report types both need to have the same primary object. I figured any 2 report types, which both had lookups to a common object would do. I use to think joined reports were nearly worthless lol